# How do I get user specific pages using javascript only?

Tags: javascript, mod-rewrite

I am creating a website where each user will have their uniq page. users can visit other user's pages by

```
http://website/user?user=<username>&session=<session>
```

Now I want to simplify above URL to

```
http://website/user/<username> (something like pinterest or facebook)
```

I thought I can use mod_rewrite. However, mod_rewrite is for server side. I do not want to include any PHP code. What I do to get data for a user :
load the basic HTML template and then based on which user we are talking about, load user's data asynchronously.

Can I achieve above in JS? If yes, how?

-Ajay

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't do exactly this.

But possible solution would be to place your HTML hub page to `http://website/user/` and form user URLs like this: `http://website/user/#username`. JS can get the user name simply by `var username = location.href.split("#")[1]`.

By the way, you said that you are not using PHP. How do you parse URL arguments then?

Comment: function getParameterByName(name) {
   name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
   var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)");
                        
   results = regex.exec(location.search);
   return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
  }

Comment: Cool. Where do you store users?

Comment: server :P. where else?

Comment: I get my data from web services that is hosted somewhere else. On my side i only want to have client side coding. Looks like i will need to introduce some server side coding on my side